# pandas permute values within range to create bins

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
stu_id,Mat_score,sci_score,Eng_score
1,1,1,1
2,1,5,1
3,5,5,5
4,1,2,5
5,4,5,5
6,3,3,3
7,1,1,3
8,3,3,1
9,1,1,5
10,3,4,3

df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

I would like to create a new column called `study_group` based on below criteria

if a student has score of `5,5,5` and `4,4,4` or `4,5,5` or `4,5,4` or `5,4,4` then assign him to `study_group` called `champion`.

if a student has score of `1,1,1` or `1,2,1` or `2,2,1` or `1,1,2` or `2,2,2` or `2,1,1` etc, then assign to him to `lost`

if a student has a score of `3,3,3` or `3,2,3` or `3,4,3` or `3,5,3` etc, then assign to him to `moderate to good`

if a student has a score of `3,1,1` or `1,3,3` or `3,1,3` or `1,1,3` etc, then assign to him to `poor to moderate`

So, if the score doesn't fall under any of the ranges that I have given above, then they should be assigned to `Other`

So, I was trying something like below

```
study_group = []
for row in df1.iterrows():
            rec = row[1]
            m = rec['Mat_score']
            s = rec['sci_score']
            e = rec['Eng_score']
            if (m in (4,5)) & (s in (4,5)) & (e in (4,5)):
                study_group.append({rec['stu_id']:'Champion'})
            elif (m in (1,2)) & (s in (1,2)) & (e in (1,2)):
                study_group.append({rec['stu_id']:'Lost'})
            elif (m in (3)) & (s in (2,3,4,5)) & (e in (3)):
                study_group.append({rec['stu_id']:'moderate to good'})
            elif (m in (1,3)) & (s in (1,3)) & (e in (1,3)):
                study_group.append({rec['stu_id']:'Poor to moderate'})
            else:
                study_group.append({rec['stu_id']:'Other'})
```

But am not sure whether the above code is elegant and efficient. I have to write if-else for multiple different combinations

Is there any other efficient and elegant approach to do the above?

I expect my output to be like as below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `np.select`

```py
score = df.filter(like='score')

df['study_group'] = np.select(
    [score.isin([4,5]).all(axis=1),
     score.isin([1,2]).all(axis=1),
     (score[['Mat_score', 'Eng_score']].eq(3).all(axis=1) & score['sci_score'].ne(1)),
     score.isin([1,3]).all(axis=1)],
    ['Champion',
     'Lost',
     'moderate to good',
     'Poor to moderate'],
    default='Other'
)
```

```
print(df)

   stu_id  Mat_score  sci_score  Eng_score       study_group
0       1          1          1          1              Lost
1       2          1          5          1             Other
2       3          5          5          5          Champion
3       4          1          2          5             Other
4       5          4          5          5          Champion
5       6          3          3          3  moderate to good
6       7          1          1          3  Poor to moderate
7       8          3          3          1  Poor to moderate
8       9          1          1          5             Other
9      10          3          4          3  moderate to good
```